# Why is this environment variable not set up?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, quoting

1. When a shell runs an external executable as a command, we can pass
   environment variables into the executable.

   ```
   $ var=3 /bin/echo `$var`

   $ var=3 bash -c "/bin/echo '$var'"
   ```

   both don't output anything.
2. When  a program is executed by `exec`, I want to see if environment
   variable also works:

   ```
   $ bash
   $ unset var; 
   $ var=3 exec /bin/echo '$var'
   $var
   $ exec var=3 /bin/echo '$var'
   bash: exec: var=3: not found
   ```

To prevent variable expansion, I use single quote around `$var`.
The protection seems a little too much.

Why is this environment variable not set up in the above cases?

Can I make environment variables work for a program executed by `exec`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- All your problems are related to quoting, not environment.

  1. Environment for a command.

     > When a shell runs an external executable as a command, we can pass environment variables into the executable.

  Yes, that's a way to set environment variables for a command, external or otherwise.

  But what you are missing in this line<sup>[a]</sup>:

  ```
  $ var=3 /bin/echo "$var"
  ```

  Is that the shell expands the variable when building the arguments, and, if the variable `var` is not set in the shell which starts the command, this is what is actually executed:

  ```
  $ var=3 /bin/echo ""
  ```

  To actually see the present shell expansion, run this:

  ```
  $ var=RunningShell ;   var=3 /bin/echo "$var"
  RunningShell
  ```

  One (often times insecure) way to delay the evaluation of the variable is:

  ```
  $ var=3 eval /bin/echo '"$var"'
  3
  ```

  On the second example you have the quotes exchanged:

  ```
  $ var=3 bash -c "/bin/echo '$var'"
  ```

  Prints nothing as the actual command line becomes:

  ```
  $ var=3 bash -c "/bin/echo ''"
  ```

  As the value of the (unset) variable $var is expanded. You probably meant this:

  ```
  $ var=thisis3 bash -c '/bin/echo "$var"'
  thisis3
  ```

  In which case the single quotes prevent the expansion of the variable by the executing shell, leaving the expansion to the executed shell (`bash -c`).

  - Use env to actually see the environment.

    2. When a program is executed by exec, I want to see if environment variable also works:

  Do not exec in your present shell as it will close the running shell.
  You may do this to avoid closing the running shell:

  ```
  $ var=3 exec /bin/echo \$var | cat
  $var
  ```

  As the closed shell will be the one that would be closed anyway, the first sub-shell of a pipe.

  But that will not show you the value of var in the environment. To see variables in the environment, use the command to see the environment:

  ```
  $ var=3 env | grep var
  var=3
  ```

---

<sup>[a]</sup>
The command you wrote had backquotes `` ` ``, changing them to single quotes will avoid the expansion of the variable and will print `$var`.:

```
$ var=3 /bin/echo '$var'
$var
```

Comment: Thanks. I  am stuck at two examples in our discussion https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384801. How would you understand them? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that parameter expansion doesn’t happen magically, you need a shell to do it for you.

```
var=3 /bin/echo `$var`
```

I’m not sure what you’re trying to do with that one, back-ticks aren’t appropriate here (they execute a command and are replaced with its output).

```
var=3 bash -c "/bin/echo '$var'"
```

doesn’t work because parameter expansion occurs before the assignment, so the current shell changes `"/bin/echo '$var'"` to `/bin/echo ''` (assuming `var` is undefined), and the child shell is run with

```
/bin/echo ''
```

Try

```
var=3 bash -c 'echo $var'
```

instead: the single quotes here protect the argument from the current shell, and the new shell is run with

```
echo $var
```

which it will process as you’d expect.

In your second point, my initial comment still applies. If you want to play around with the environment and see what happens, run `env` and filter its output instead:

```
var=3 env | grep var
var=3 exec env | grep var
```

Comment: Thanks. i noticed something perhaps incorrect. and changed it.

Comment: @Tim could you explain your change? I think it’s wrong...

Comment: When a shell sees `var=3 bash -c "/bin/echo '$var'"`, the single quotes within the double quotes are literal, so don't prevent parameter expansion `$var` in the shell, where `var` is unset. So the child shell which the shell forks to execute the double quoted content sees `/bin/echo ''`. See Arrow's answer.

Comment: Still not correct. the current shell changes `"/bin/echo '$var'"` to `/bin/echo ''` (assuming `var` is undefined). parameter expansion happens before quote removal.

Comment: @Tim huh, yes, that’s what I meant to write :-/.