# Why do following output `$var` instead of `3`?

Tags: bash

Why do the following examples from [Arrow's reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/382995/674) output `$var` instead of `3`?

I single quote or backslash `$var` as `'$var'` or `\$var`, hoping that

- first `$var` will be passed literally into the execution environment of the executable program `/bin/echo`, and
- then inside the execution environment of the executable program `/bin/echo`, the environment variable `var=3` applies when parameter expansion happens on `$var`.

Why doesn't the parameter expansion happen inside the execution environment of the executable program `/bin/echo`? **Note:**

- in the original shell, `$var` is single quoted or backslashed, so should not be expanded in the execution environment of the original shell.
- the original shell removes the single quotes or backslash around `$var`,  and then passes `$var` and   environment variable `var=3` into the execution environment for running `/bin/echo`, so I think that parameter expansion of `$var`  should happen in the execution environment for running `/bin/echo`.

Note that I use `set -x` to print out the trace information, but [can't figure out what is actually the result after expansion but before execution.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384794/674)

Thanks.

```
tim$ unset var
$ set -x

tim$ var=3 /bin/echo '$var'
+ var=3
+ /bin/echo '$var'
$var

tim$ var=3 /bin/echo \$var
+ var=3
+ /bin/echo '$var'
$var

$ var=3 exec /bin/echo \$var | cat
+ cat
+ var=3
+ exec /bin/echo '$var'
$var

tim$ var=3 exec /bin/echo '$var' | cat
+ var=3
+ exec /bin/echo '$var'
+ cat
$var
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: Why would `/bin/echo` know or care about variable expansion? Variable expansion is a shell feature, not a property of the environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In every single case, you are either strong-quoting, which prevents expansion of the variable; or escaping the `$` character, which also makes it no longer a variable subject to expansion.  `/bin/echo` and `cat` doesn't do any parameter or variable expansion whatsoever, so piping into it would not cause such to occur.